# SQL Join Between Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Below are my two tables structure,

```
mysql> desc catalog_product_entity;
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type                 | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| entity_id        | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| entity_type_id   | smallint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| attribute_set_id | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| type_id          | varchar(32)          | NO   |     | simple              |                |
| sku              | varchar(64)          | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| created_at       | datetime             | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at       | datetime             | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| has_options      | smallint(1)          | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| required_options | tinyint(1) unsigned  | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| user_id          | mediumint(11)        | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc catalog_product_entity_varchar;
+----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| value_id       | int(11)               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| entity_type_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| attribute_id   | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| store_id       | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| entity_id      | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| value          | varchar(255)          | NO   |     |         |                |
+----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to join two tables based on following criteria,

I want to fetch all values form second table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` where entity_id should match with first table `catalog_product_entity` and where user_id from first table is `12`.

Below is my sql query -

```
select entity_id, value, COUNT(*) as count 
    from catalog_product_entity_varchar as cpev 
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity as cpe on cpe.entity_id = cpev.entity_id 
    where attribute_id = '960' 
    GROUP BY value 
    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1) 
    limit 1
```

**Updates -**

I have updated my sql query,
But it shows only one result not multiple results.

```
select catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id,
       catalog_product_entity_varchar.value, COUNT(*) as count,
       catalog_product_entity.entity_id, catalog_product_entity.user_id
from catalog_product_entity_varchar,
     catalog_product_entity
where attribute_id = '960'
  and catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id
  AND catalog_product_entity.user_id = '12'
GROUP BY value
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
limit 1;
```

Current Result -

```
+-----------+---------------+-------+-----------+---------+
| entity_id | value         | count | entity_id | user_id |
+-----------+---------------+-------+-----------+---------+
|  11062505 | 05-04100262-R |     2 |  11062505 |      12 |
+-----------+---------------+-------+-----------+---------+
1 row in set (36.67 sec)
```

Expected Result -

```
+-----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+---------------+
| value_id  | entity_type_id | attribute_id | store_id | entity_id | value         |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+---------------+
|  63606647 |             10 |          960 |        0 |  11062505 | 05-04100262-R |
| 149826537 |             10 |          960 |        0 |  19987372 | 05-04100262-R |
+-----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+---------------+
2 rows in set (12.84 sec)
```

And also can we optimise this query because current query is taking too much time

Comment: Do explain what is wrong with the query, what it gives as opposed to how it should be.

Comment: Could you make your intention clearly? Where is the condition `user_id` is `12` in your query? And other conditions in your query don't match the intention you describe before?

Comment: You are doing a GROUP BY on the value column, but bringing back the entity_id column as well. Which value of entity_id is brought back for a value is undefined.

Comment: please check updated question guys.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Even ignoring the issue with GROUP BY, you are using _LIMIT 1_ so will only return a single row.

Comment: Limit one is just for testing purposes.. It doesnt matter

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to require is a simple join, far simpler than the example SQL you have posted.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT cpev.value_id,
        cpev.entity_type_id,
        cpev.attribute_id,
        cpev.store_id,
        cpev.entity_id,
        cpev.value
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar as cpev 
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity as cpe on cpe.entity_id = cpev.entity_id 
WHERE  cpe.user_id = 12
```

However I suspect you have missed something in your requirements.

EDIT

I think what you are trying to do is find all the values which occur more than once, and then bring back the records that have that value. If so use a sub query to get back the values used more than once, and then join that back against your main tables again:-

```
SELECT cpev.value_id,
        cpev.entity_type_id,
        cpev.attribute_id,
        cpev.store_id,
        cpev.entity_id,
        cpev.value
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev 
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe ON cpe.entity_id = cpev.entity_id 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT cpev.value, 
            COUNT(*) AS value_count 
    FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev 
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe ON cpe.entity_id = cpev.entity_id 
    WHERE cpev.attribute_id = '960' 
    AND  cpe.user_id = 12
    GROUP BY value 
    HAVING value_count > 1
) sub0
ON cpev.value = sub0.value
WHERE cpev.attribute_id = '960' 
AND  cpe.user_id = 12
```

Comment: I think in your answer we need to define table as first then define that column name

Comment: @John - The problem is the GROUP BY clause in your SQL. But we need to know what columns you want to group by and how. Note that every returned column group either be an aggregate result (ie, COUNT(), MAX(), etc) or a column that is listed in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Kickstart I want group by value which having count greater than 1.

Comment: This is you query updated as I want, but it giving error on attribute_id  - `SELECT cpev.entity_id, cpev.value, COUNT(value) as count FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar as cpev INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity as cpe on cpe.entity_id = cpev.entity_id WHERE  cpe.user_id = 12 cpev.attribute_id = '960' GROUP BY cpev.value HAVING (COUNT(value) > 1)  limit 1;`

Comment: But if you GROUP BY the value column, then only one row will be returned for that value. Do you mean that you want to find the values that occur more than once, and then bring back all the rows that have that value?

Comment: @John - added a suggestion for what I _think_ you want

Comment: Yes I want  all the entity_id having same value in `value` column.

Comment: What is `sub0` here ? Also I want to suggest you that user_id is form `cpe` table

Comment: @John - sub0 is the alias name for the sub query (sub queries used like this MUST have an alias name).

Comment: your first query works but only returns single result when add Group BY clause. and retrun different results without clause. Second query using subquery not working.

Comment: @John - GROUP BY will dramatically change the results, and depending on the fields you use GROUP BY on the results will also vary. It was set up for your initial requirement before you gave any more details. The 2nd query (or something similar) is what you need. In what way does it not work? Can you export the table declares and some test data so I have a chance of testing it please?